# How can I match HTML elements with regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, .net-4.0

The following codes does not work, I am trying to retrive TR strings from a HTML table. Is there any issue with this code or any other solution available?

```
public static List<string> GetTR(string Tr)
{
    List<string> trContents = new List<string>();

    string regexTR = @"<(tr|TR)[^<]+>((\s*?.*?)*?)<\/(tr|TR)>";

    MatchCollection tr_Matches = Regex.Matches(Tr, regexTR, RegexOptions.Singleline);
    foreach (Match match in tr_Matches)
    {
        trContents.Add(match.Value);
    }

    return trContents;
}
```

Sample input string is given below:

```
"<TR><TD noWrap align=left>abcd</TD><TD noWrap align=left>SPORT</TD><TD align=left>5AT</TD></TR>"
```

Comment: Required reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 - or in summary: **don't use regex to parse HTML**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parsing HTML with regular expressions is asking for trouble.

Do the job properly using something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Comment: "Parsing HTML with regular expressions is asking for trouble." seems to become a regular expression here....

Comment: but its true ... since HTML is not necessarily regular

Comment: overwhelmed by the swift response, thank you LukeH & ChosPandion. let me try the HTML Agility Pack.

Answer (score 0):

I think this regular expression would be more appropriate:

```
<(tr|TR)[^>]*>.*<\/\1>
```

Answer (score 0):

this regex matches your input string:

```
<(tr|TR)+>((\s*?.*?)*?)<\/(tr|TR)>
```

i removed "[^<]"... not sure why you need that. also, try to add a non-greedy match...

however, it is better to go with something like HTML Agility Pak (if you want to keep your sanity) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
(<(tr|TR)[^<]*>)(.+)((<\(tr|TR)[^<]*>)
```